# Kurento : Lossy Network Audio on priority

Tags: kurento

I want to know that is there any possible configuration which can be done to make kurento media server give priority to audio stream when there is slow/lossy network detected.

Is it possible ?

also are there any configurations which can be done to handle the video bitrate on the fly to make KMS more efficient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adjusting the bitrate there a function from kurento. .setOutputBitrate(). [more info](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/langdoc/javadoc/org/kurento/client/MediaElement.html#setOutputBitrate(int)).
This can be set before the ice candidates negotiations are made with that endpoint. If you want to change you will have to renegotiate. A reference link from another forum is [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kurento/bK4SdL-XhCI/9hxrPci4BAAJ).